# While on Windows 10, what is the difference between typing "bash" in the command prompt, and running a Ubuntu instance?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash

When I open Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I have some set of files and folders available to me, but when I run "bash" on CMD I have a different set of files and folders. As far as I can see, I can't access the files from Ubuntu from bash CMD or vice versa. What are the differences between these two?

Comment: When you use Ubuntu "Windows Subsystem for Linux" it is an entire Ubuntu Installation on Windows certified by Microsoft. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Bash-on-Ubuntu-and-Windows-and-Git-Bash

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a question of who wrote your terminal application.  In both cases bash is running in a terminal window.  One was published by Microsoft exclusively in Windows, and the other is an open-source terminal integrated into the Debian software stack.  If you are thinking of a more specific way of them being different, please let me know.